# Manual test steps with serenity screenplay pattern

Tags: serenity-bdd

Does anyone know if there is a way to list the test steps of manual tests [like seen here](https://serenity-bdd.github.io/theserenitybook/latest/manual-tests.html) without using cucumber.
I am using the screenplay pattern like this

```
@Test
@Manual(result = TestResult.UNSUCCESSFUL, reason = "test steps unclear")
public void exampleTest() {
    givenThat(actor).wasAbleTo(new DoSomething());
    when(actor).attemptsTo(new DoSomethingElse());
    then(actor).should(seeThat("what?", a-> true, Is.is(true)));
}
```

But the steps don't show up in the `bdd` report